# NoMethodError in Static_pages#resume (undefined method `resumes_path')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path

It was working fine before but I'm getting this error now

I'm getting the error when I try to click on or browse to path `/resume`

Here is how I have it inside routes.rb

```
match '/resume', to: 'static_pages#resume'
```

Then, here's the static_pages controller for that

```
 def resume
    if signed_in?
    @resume = current_user.resumes.build
  end
end
```

Here's the static_pages\resume.html view causing the error

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<%= form_for @resume, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @resume %>
    <div class="ItemInput">Add your file:<br>
  <%= f.file_field :content %>
</div>
<center><%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's telling me that this line `<%= form_for @resume, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>` is causing it. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have route only for /resume. You should add routes for the POST method, for your form

Add this to your routes

```
match '/resumes' => 'static_pages#create', :via => [:post]
```

or

```
resources :resumes #This will need resumes controller and actions
```

Comment: should it be 'static_pages#create' or 'static_pages#resume'? I tried adding `:via => [:post]` but it gives me this error: `No route matches [GET] "/resume"`

Comment: You need two routes. One for the get method which displays the form and another for the post method which submits your form. You will need two controller actions also.

Comment: how can I define the get part to display the form? I am going to worry about the post later

Comment: The route and action you have written is enough for get part. But in your view, you are calling form_for(@resume). This will try to create a form action url, but your routes is missing that url. This is causing the error

Comment: so I can have these two in the routes? `match '/resumes' => 'static_pages#resume'` and `match '/resumes' => 'static_pages#create', :via => [:post]`

Comment: sorry for the questions, but in what way do I need to modify my view code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29647/discussion-between-santhosh-and-user2159586)